# Windows: Disable folder type detection in explorer globally

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

In Windows Explorer (Win7-10) the folder's type is detected automatically by the files in it (e.g., music).
I can disable this on folder base manually in the properties of each folder (and its subfolder). But this creates a lot of desktop.ini files.

Is there a way to disable the folder type detection on a system based level - like "Windows should never detect the folder types on its own and should always use the plain file view"?

Comment: Note - this behaviour was actually introduced in Vista, not Win7.  I believe the solution described below will also work in Vista (although I don't have an installed machine to test it on so can't be certain).

Comment: Also a duplicate of this question: [Irritating auto-changing column types in Windows Explorer in case of audio/video files](https://superuser.com/questions/513298/irritating-auto-changing-column-types-in-windows-explorer-in-case-of-audio-video).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**This method will require modifying your registry**

1. Start by opening `regedit` (in Windows 7 go to Start Menu > Run and enter `regedit`; for Windows 10 just click Start Menu and start typing `regedit` and hit Enter)
2. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell`
3. Delete both of the following keys: `Bags` and `BagMRU`
4. Right-click on the `Shell` key and select `New > Key` and name it `Bags`
5. Right-click on `Bags` key and select `New > Key` and name it `AllFolders`
6. Right-click on `AllFolders` key and select `New > Key` and name it `Shell`
7. Right-click on `Shell` key and select `New > String Value` name it `FolderType`
8. Double-click on `FolderType` in the right window pane to bring up the `Edit String` option.
9. In the `Value Data` filed enter `NotSpecified`
   [image]
10. Now close regedit and you're done. Windows Explorer will no longer detect the folder's type and change the view.

Comment: FYI this is still working in 2020 on Win10 version 2004. And thank goodness because the default behavior is obnoxious.

Comment: I am looking for how to do the opposite - to **re-enable** automatic detection of new folder's type. When I create a new folder, paste the image, go one folder up and then return to the new folder the view is not changed to Picture view as before - now every new folder has list view regardless of the containing files type.

Comment: What if I don't have those keys, but do have nested folders with those names? Was this changed for 2021?
Screenshot:

https://imgur.com/LopslcY

Comment: Not sure if editing in the .reg contents for this change would be too big a change to this answer so here are the entries for this change: `[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags]
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell]
"FolderType"="NotSpecified"`

Comment: @DAG works on Win10 22H2 as well. After disabling this, File explorer became blazing fast again..

Comment: No, this not work, It just reset the already setted folder type, it won't stop the automatically detection of  folder type.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working in Windows 10 as of March 18, 2024.

Explorer continues to change the view depending on the file types it finds.  I've triple-checked the registry path and settings