# Disable automatic customising folders in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, mp3

Windows File Explorer has long had a feature whereby it tries to customise folders based on what files are in there.  Is there any way to disable this in Windows 10?

Specifically I have a problem that I create a lot of audio-visual files, and this leads Windows to often re-categorise folders as music - so that File explorer in detail mode displays columns like 'artist' and 'album'. I basically NEVER want this, and I therefore seem to be forever manually changing folders back to 'documents' (by right-clicking in File Explorer and selecting 'Customise').  Frustratingly, Windows invariably then re-categorises the folder back to 'music' as soon as I add a couple more .mp3's to the folder, so I have to manually change it back again.

Hence my question: How can I stop Windows doing this? I don't really want to change things on a per-folder basis (because this problem affects a lot of folders) - I would prefer to just change one setting to stop Windows ever auto-customising any folder anywhere on my file system.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Irritating auto-changing column types in Windows Explorer in case of audio/video files](https://superuser.com/questions/513298/irritating-auto-changing-column-types-in-windows-explorer-in-case-of-audio-video) Especially [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1265125/62676) is IMHO very helpful.

Comment: You have verified this works in W10 as the regedit suggested is for W10 @Robert

Comment: Simon see this page>>>>https://winaero.com/blog/disable-folder-type-discovery-windows-10/

Comment: Thanks guys. I've tried the regit solution mentioned in both the other StackExchange question and the winaero link, so will see if that works.....